# How to solve CORS error firebase cloud function?

Tags: javascript, cors, google-cloud-functions

How to solve CORS error? I have CORS error on testing really simple function pls help me

```
         const functions = require('firebase-functions');
         const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
         import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
         admin.initializeApp();

          exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
            res.send("hello!!");
           });

          //on calling in .js file

           var test = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');
           test().then(function(result) {});
```

Comment: Setting the `Access-Control-...` headers in the *request* does nothing, as those are *response* headers received from the destination server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to call API from different external domains and API from cloud function. And they are working absolutely fine for me.

If you can share some instances of code so I will verify that.

**Edit:**

```
exports.fetchClientToken = functions.https.onRequest(
async (request, response) => {
const clientToken = await fetch("https://**/api/Token", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: "Username=*&Password=*&grant_type=password"
 });
 let tokenResponse = await clientToken.json();
 response.send(tokenResponse);
});
```

And I am calling it as,

```
 const firebaseTokenMethod = await fetch("https://us-central1-*-1106.cloudfunctions.net/fetchClientToken",
 {
   method: "POST",
   headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/json",
   }
 });

let token = await firebaseTokenMethod.json();
```

It working very fine for me!!. I don't need any import CORS and all.

Comment: I already have CORS error on testing really simple function see code above pls

Comment: I have edited my answer have a look

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling for few hours, and I found the error for "fetch() is not defined" and I had to npm install fetch --save What a waste time!! but Thanks man